# Refresh after history.replact

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have created a `requireAuth` function in my index.js to allow just the user, after login, to get data. I set it up like this:

```
function requireAuth(nextState, replace) {
    console.log(auth.loggedIn());
    if (!auth.loggedIn()) {
        history.push('/login')
        console.log("NOT LOGGED IN")
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
  <HashRouter history={history}>
      <Switch>
          <Route path="/restaurant" name="Restaurant" component={RestrauntDashboard} onEnter={requireAuth()}/>
          <Route path="/" name="Home" component={Home} />
      </Switch>
  </HashRouter>
</Provider>,
document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

But after logout I am still can access to my path "/restaurant", just if I refresh the page this is redirect me to the '/login' path, someone have an idea? Thank you for your help.

My history is set up like this:

```
import { createHashHistory } from 'history';

export const history = createHashHistory({
    forceRefresh: true
})
```